# Php Switch Wont Require

Tags: php, switch-statement

i can get my switch function to require or include files, it works because it echos but i cant get it to require, or include in that matter, no idea why :( i would appreciate any help, what am im doing wrong?

```
<form name="select-action" action="" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'select_action_form', 'select_generate_nonce' ); ?>
    <select name="actions-picker">
        <option value="action_create" name="cj-create">Create A New List</option>
        <option value="action_edit" name="cj-edit">Edit Existing List</option>
        <option value="action_delete" name="cj-delete">Delete A List</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-action" value="Launch!">
</form>
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit-action'] ) ) {

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['select_generate_nonce'], 'select_action_form' ) ) {
        wp_die( 'Our Plugin Is Secure Go Get Coffee!' );
    } else {

        $action = $_POST['actions-picker'];
        switch ( $action ) {

            case 'action_create' :
                require ( 'test.php' );
                break;
            case  'action_edit' :
                echo 'B';
                break;
            case  'action_delete' :
                echo 'C';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is not working. Question is bit unclear. Please elaborate

Comment: the cases wont require files, for example case 1 is true but the switch wont require the file test.php

Comment: you need if-else for that. switch will not work, i think

Comment: Knowing that it doesn't work implies an error being thrown or an expected side-effect from `test.php` that doesn't happen? If it's the latter then can you also share `test.php` just in case there's something else going on there? If it's the former then can you also share the error message?

Comment: Explain Clearly...

Comment: no error msg, test.php has only a single line of code for testing, echo hi

Comment: Explain Clearly... – as i said the switch case wont require the file... i dont know how i can explain it clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.......
else {
    $action = $_POST['actions-picker'];
    switch ( $action ) {

        case 'action_create' :
            ob_start();
            require ( 'test.php' );
            $output = ob_get_clean();
            echo $output;
            break;
        case  'action_edit' :
            echo 'B';
            break;
        case  'action_delete' :
            echo 'C';
    }
}
.......
```

Comment: Omg, buffering, right ! would have taken me along time to figure this one out lol, thanks Lexx and thanks everyone for trying to help !